# Connecting to an Oracle Pluggable Database using connection string in .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, oracle, pluggable-database

How can we connect to a pluggable database via connection string in my application?

Pluggable database is created via docker.

How do I specify that I want to connect to a pluggable database and not to cdb? Because am getting lot of metadata tables when connected to cdb.

Can we provide service name as an attribute in connection string?
I was able to create a connection for my pdb via sql developer, issue is only when I try from code.

Please let me know if you have any solution

I tried using the following connection string but both throwed some error:

```
var connection string = "User ID=sys; 
Password = password;
DBA Privilege = sysdba; 
Data Source = freepdb1";
```

Also tried passing localhost

```
var connection string = "User ID=sys; 
Password = password;
DBA Privilege = sysdba; 
Data Source = localhost/freepdb1";
```

Comment: knowing WHAT error you got would help

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified\n Inner Exception - OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'll need the EZCONNECT syntax, namely:

```
Data Source = //localhost/freepdb1
```

Depending on the Oracle client you are using, check also the sqlnet.ora file to ensure it has something like this:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

so that EZCONNECT is supported.

Comment: Tried User ID=sys;Password = password;DBA Privilege = sysdba;Data Source = //localhost/freepdb1; But getting error: Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure\n Inner Exception - OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException.    sqlnet.ora file does have EZCONNECT